# Facebook Oauth on Cloud9

Tags: facebook, oauth, cloud9-ide

Facebook requires a `website URL`, where the website is hosted for validating Oauth requests. Facebook also requires valid `callback URLs`, basically a list of URLs that Facebook can securely pass Oauth tokens to.

Here's the difference in my local environment versus my cloud9 environment, concerning Facebook Oauth setup:

**Localhost**:

- *website URL*: `http://localhost:3000`
- *callback URL*: `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

**Cloud9**:

- *website URL*: `http://myapp-cireficc.c9.io/`
- *callback URL*: `http://myapp-cireficc.c9.io/auth/facebook/callback`

My localhost setup works just fine. However, when I run my app on cloud9, I get the following error from Facebook:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

This is implying that one of these two parameters are wrong... and after a bit of debugging, it looks like Facebook is trying to access ***this*** callback URL:

`redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp-cireficc.c9.io%3A80%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback`

And after decoding that into more readable characters, we have:

`http://myapp-cireficc.c9.io:80/auth/facebook/callback`

It seems like this random ***:80*** is being added to the callback URL, which makes me think that when the Oauth request gets sent out, it's being appended, and Facebook is just dutifully attaching it to the response callback, which is now **incorrect**. Because the **:80** is being added, the *expected* and *actual* callbacks differ:

**expected**: `http://myapp-cireficc.c9.io/auth/facebook/callback`

**actual**: `http://myapp-cireficc.c9.io:80/auth/facebook/callback`

This seems to me to be something cloud9 is adding when it sends out the request (maybe due to how their domain names are set up?). What can I do to get Facebook Oauth working on cloud9?

**Note**: Cloud9's `env.PORT` is `8080`, and `env.IP` is `0.0.0.0`. This seems to be where the **:80** in the callback is coming from, but I have no idea how to get around the issue.

Interestingly enough, I have my *staging* environment set up on Heroku, and Heroku doesn't have this issue. I can easily access Facebook Oauth there by using `http://myapp-staging.herokuapp.com` and the correct callback URL.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. You could add :80 to the website URL to get around this for now though.

Comment: @Mutahhir Yeah I have no idea why it's happening. I had tried that when I first realized the problem, but the server was hanging. It turns out I was missing something for setup of the database, so the 'find user' function timed out. In any case, appending `:80` to the URL worked, so I guess it's not that big of a deal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue: adding the port (:80) to the cloud9 url, then adding it to the Valid *OAuth redirect URIs* fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi! Where is this Valid OAuth redirect is located? On Facebook Dev dashboard? Basic or Advanced settings?

Answer (score 1):

@AnthonyGrove's answer did not work for me.

However, adding the port (:8080) to the cloud9 url, then adding it to the Valid *OAuth redirect URIs* fixed it for me.

From the [docs](https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application): `Please note that 8080, 8081, and 8082 are the only available ports on a hosted Cloud9 workspace.`